# unable to invoke firefox using gecko driver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have latest Firefox version 55.0.1(win 64) and latest gecko driver gecko-driver version 18 (win 64) 
I am not able to invoke the Firefox, I even added the latest jar of selenium 3.5
am I missing something?

---

Hi,
I have latest firefox version 55.0.1(win 64) and latest gecke driver geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64 
I am not able to invoke the firefox, I even added the latest jar of selenium 3.5
am I missing something???

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "F:\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
```

Comment: Shouldn't you double the backslashes in a string literal? like "F:\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe"

Comment: Additionally change `"webdriver.firefox.bin"` to `"webdriver.gecko.driver"`

Comment: Did you set the path of the gecko driver in system variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code would be as below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
```

Change `webdriver.firefox.bin` to `webdriver.gecko.driver` since you are going to utilize gecko driver.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Any reason to mix up a `\\ ` and a `/ ` in a `value` field?

Comment: Not in particular, its just how I started using it long back. So became a habit. Is it a wrong way?

Comment: Can't point you to a documentation right away but the mix-up seems unnecessary and may prove hard for a beginner to understand.

Comment: Changed to `\\ ` ;)

Comment: now it have invoked Firefox, but still it is not entering URL in urlbox :(

Answer (score 0):

You need also to add this dependency in the pom.xml in order your code run successfully because you have used Selenium 3.5:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```